# Canonical Coupling of Stochastically Dominating RVs?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Is it true that if $X \succeq Y$, i.e. $X$ stochastically dominates $Y$, then there exists a coupling of $X,Y$ such that $X \geq Y a.s.$? If so, is there a canonical way to construct such a coupling (like in the case of TV-distance, where we have a canonical way to construct the coupling that achieves the TV-distance between the RVs)?

Comment: What definition of stochastic domination are you using? I've only been familiar with the notion you described as being the defining property of stochastic domination. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance#Equivalent_definitions) if your definition involves the ordering of CDFs, then these notions are equivalent for integrable random variables.